# Vue -- waiting for mapState and the dreaded [__ob__: Observer]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is deep watch the best / correct way to wait for a mapState object to be available? I sometimes have massive objects that get transformed and committed as new objects and that can take a few ms.

```
watch: {
  calendarData: {
    handler(newVal) {
      newVal.forEach((ev) => {
        // do something
      });
    },
    deep: true,
  },
},
```